# Trying to scrape and I cant get past a "Notices" splash page - "Clicking" a JS button with python requests

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

Like the title says, I am stuck on whats probably a very simple problem. I'm scraping a website that involves a couple steps before accessing the data I want. First you have to login, which I've done with a post. Then you have to click an "OK" button agreeing to new terms/announcements/notices. You have to click OK once for each of their new notices, at this time there are 3. So you click OK on the first notice, it takes you to the second notice and so on.

I cannot figure out what I need to post to move from the first notice to the second.

---

The button HTML shows:

```
<input type="button" tabindex="1" id="BNOTACC" value="OK">
<input type="button" tabindex="1" id="BNOTCAN" value="CANCEL"> == $0
```

BNOTACC = Button Notice Accept

BNOTCAN = Button Notice Cancel

---

I've found the following JavaScript:

```
$(function(){ 
            $("#BNOTCAN").click(function(){window.location.href ="/index.cfm?zaction=LOGIN&zmethod=LOGOUT";});
            $("#BNOTACC").click(function(){AcceptNotice();});
            $("#BNOTOK").click(function(){AcceptNotice();});
            $("#NOTICEMSG").blur(function(){  $("#BNOTOK").focus();});
            $("#NOTICEMSG").blur(function(e){ $("#BNOTACC").focus();});
            $("#BNOTCAN").blur(function(e){ $("#NOTICEMSG").focus();});
            })

function AcceptNotice(){
        var NID = $("#NOTICEMSG").attr('NID');

        $.post('index.cfm',{
               zaction:'AJAX',
               zmethod:'COM',
               process:'NOTICE',
               func:'ACCEPT',
               showjson:false,
               NID:NID}, 
               function(){RefreshPage();});
    }

function RefreshPage (){
        window.location.href = "/index.cfm";
    }
```

Here I can see that click Cancel should log you out and clicking OK runs AcceptNotice() which is a just a post with a payload and then refreshes the page at which point the next notice shows up.

So I am trying the following

```
payload = {
    'zaction': 'AJAX',
    'zmethod': 'COM',
    'process': 'NOTICE',
    'func': 'ACCEPT',
    'showjson': 'false',
    'NID':''' $("#NOTICEMSG").attr('NID')'''
}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

But no matter what, I am always still at the first notice. I've found a ton of similar questions but none that seem to help me with this particular issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that the payload NID element corresponds to a specific NID in the html

The HTML also includes, a couple lines later:

```
<div id="NOTICEMSG" tabindex="0" nid="9147">
```

So my payload needed to be :

```
payload = {
    'zaction': 'AJAX',
    'zmethod': 'COM',
    'process': 'NOTICE',
    'func': 'ACCEPT',
    'showjson': 'false',
    'NID':9147
}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```